# Interaction between servlet and html

Tags: java, html, servlet-3.0

I have processed data from a servlet and I need to pass them frontend side to an html page.
How can I do without using "printwriters"?

And again, where can I study the servlets well and maybe how do they interact with the jsp?
Thank you!

Comment: JSPs are the simplest way to return HTML in Java. A JSP is just an HTML "template-able" page that is automatically bound to a servlet by the servlet container (basically your server, tomcat or anything else). Just google for `jsp tutorial` and you'll find some good stuff really quick.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you recommend me some particular site?